# Varnish 5 deafult.vcl issue

Tags: varnish-vcl

Varnish 5 failing to start if I use use vcl 5.1; or vcl 5.0; in my default.vcl

Varnish5 docs says:

Starting with Varnish 4.0, each VCL file must start by declaring its version with "vcl X.Y;" marker at the top of the file.

but I'm using Varnish 5.1

I tried vcl 5.0; or vcl 5.1; in my default.vcl but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the man page vcl(7) under VERSIONING (from a Varnish **5**.0.0 installation on Debian 9):

```
   Multiple versions of the VCL syntax can coexist  within  certain
   constraints.

   The  VCL  syntax version at the start of VCL file specified with
   ''-f'' sets the hard limit that cannot be exceeded anywhere, and
   it selects the appropriate version of the builtin VCL.

   That  means  that  you  can  never  include "vcl 9.1;" from "vcl
   8.7;", but the opposite may be possible, to the extent the  com‐
   piler supports it.

   Files pulled in via include do not need to have a "vcl X.Y;" but
   it may be a good idea to do it anyway, to not have surprises  in
   the  future.   The  syntax  version set in an included file only
   applies to that file and any files it includes  -  unless  these
   set their own VCL syntax version.

   The  version of Varnish this file belongs to supports **syntax 4.0**
   only.
```